# Is it possible to run multiple values of one variables parallel in a for loop?

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop, parallel-processing, pipe

I am trying to find a way to make a for loop run multiple values of one variable in parallel. But I don't know how to do this without splitting the variable in two.

###### Simplified example not in parallel:

```
for i in sample_1 sample_2 sample_3
do
samtools view -b -o ${i}.bam ${i}.sam
done
```

###### Output:

```
sample_1.sam sample_2.sam sample_3.sam
```

###### Idea:

```
for i in sample_1 sample_2 sample_3
do
samtools view -b -o *sample_1*.bam *sample_1*.sam|samtools view -b -o *sample_2*.bam *sample_2*.sam|samtools view -b -o *sample_3*.bam *sample_3*.sam
done
```

How can I achieve something like this?

Answer (score 2):

Run the commands in the background by appending `&`, then after the loop `wait` for them to finish:

```
for i in sample_1 sample_2 sample_3
do
samtools view -b -o ${i}.bam ${i}.sam &
done
wait
```

Comment: For safety I recommend to use `samtools view -b -o "${i}.bam" "${i}.sam" &`.